# Sonarqube API - search projects by passing a wild card

Tags: sonarqube

Is there an api in sonarqube (old and new versions) to get projects by passing a key with '*'.

Example : http://localhost/api/resources?format=json&key=sonar*

Or is there an alternative way to get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SonarQube v6.3:

> *api/components/search* - Search for components - Parameter *q* :
>   *Limit search to component names or **component keys** that contain the supplied string*

Before SonarQube v6.3 (only for searching on project *name* there):

> *api/projects/index* - Parameter *search*: *Substring of project **name**, case insensitive*

Source: [SonarQube WebAPI](https://sonarqube.com/web_api) (documentation [embedded](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API)  in any SonarQube instance).

Comment: It would have helped if the actual curl command was provided as part of the answer. I am still not able to figure out the answer based on the links provided.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer marked as the best answer. The information is poorly constructed.

Comment: The question is about wildcard, the answer is about components being taken into account in search with recent API.